# Best way to achieve blockUI functionality WITHOUT using jQuery or any other library?

Tags: javascript

As much as I love jQuery, it is not always possible to use open source libraries (for reasons having nothing to do with technology). How best to achieve BlockUI functionality using raw javascript?  I am really only interested in making it obvious to the user that the browser is busy, and preventing the user from making any more selections.  My jQuery-less situations happen to involve only IE 6, so IE 6 is all I'm interested in at this time.  I'm trying to avoid a "copy/paste the relevant parts of BlockUI" type of solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general idea is to create a div that covers the entire viewport and has a high z-index, with some level of opacity set. A quick look at the BlockUI source should help you to write your own.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a better solution than essentially copying BlockUI. But perhaps there really is no better solution.

Comment: If you're not allowed to use a library, then probably not

Comment: This is basically what I did.  The jQuery plugins are an absolute gold mine of useful techniques!